# How are AbsoluteExpiration, AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow and SlidingExpiration used on DistributedCacheEntryOptions?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, distributed-caching

I'm in charge of implementing a session state server with ASP.NET Core gRPC, and its corresponding client, to have session state management for a load-balanced group of ASP.NET Core applications. That means the client must implement `IDistributedCache` for that.

The methods `Set` and `SetAsync` have a parameter of type `DistributedCacheEntryOptions` and this class has the properties `AbsoluteExpiration`, `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` and `SlidingExpiration`. I presume these properties can be used to signal when a cache entry has expired, but how are they used and how am I to interpret them? Seeing that the 3 properties are nullables, is it that only one of the three is to be populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as far as I can tell, you're supposed to use only one of those properties (the one that matches your use case). In my case, all I had to do is to use `SlidingExpiration` and that covered my use case. Other contexts might require other strategies.